# Delphi: Goto not considered harmful in this case?

Tags: delphi, goto

Alright, so you have a TObjectList instance. You want to loop through the items in it and delete some of the objects from the list. You can't do this:

```
for I := 0 to ObjectList.Count - 1 do
  if TMyClass(ObjectList[I]).ShouldRemove then
    ObjectList.Delete(I);
```

...because once you delete the first object the index counter I will be all wrong and the loop won't work any more.

So here is my solution:

```
Again:
  for I := 0 to ObjectList.Count - 1 do
    if TMyClass(ObjectList[I]).ShouldRemove then
    begin
      ObjectList.Delete(I);
      goto Again;
    end;
```

This is the best solution I've found to this so far. If anyone has a neater solution I'd love to see it.

Comment: Wait... Does that mean that in Delphi, `ObjectList[k]` has complexity O(k) (when `ObjectList` is a list)? In this case, your algorithm has the wrong complexity to  start with. If you are handling lists, you should have the proper operations on lists and not be writing `for` loops, and then you would not be wondering about `goto` (although you may be wondering about exceptions).

Comment: I'm looping because I want to remove several items from the list. Otherwise I'd just use ObjectList.Remove(ObjectToRemove);

Comment: @David I understand that much, and perhaps I just shouldn't be mucking with questions about languages I am not that familiar with, but if `ObjectList[k]` has complexity O(k) (and I suspect it has), your implementation language is forcing you to write algorithms with the wrong complexity. It's time to switch... There are languages in which you can remove elements you ShouldRemove from a list in O(length).

Comment: ObjectList[k] accesses the object directly. It doesn't need to loop through 0..k to find the correct object.

Comment: @david Fair enough, I'm out of my depth here (although I would like to see the implementation of that data structure that lets you remove some elements but has O(1) access time to the nth element).

Comment: function TList.Get(Index: Integer): Pointer;
    begin
      if Cardinal(Index) >= Cardinal(FCount) then
        Error(@SListIndexError, Index);
       Result := FList^[Index];
    end;

Comment: Even though the access time for ObjectList[k] is O(1), the whole algorithm could be O(n^2) for some inputs. Consider the case where you need to remove every other element. The first element would then be checked for ShouldRemove n times. After removing the second element, the third element would be checked n-2 times and so on.

Comment: @Pascal - Delphi's base "List" object is effectively a wrapper around an array, it isn't a linked list. Early versions (1-3) of Delphi didn't have resizable arrays, so it handles the allocation and reallocation for you

Comment: Note that having to re-enter the loop each time you delete something, and thus re-iterate through items that you've already skipped over, is going to result in an performance problem that grows exponentially with large ObjectLists. That makes this approch REALLY * REALLY inefficient.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
 for I := ObjectList.Count - 1 downto 0 do
   if TMyClass(ObjectList[I]).ShouldRemove then
     ObjectList.Delete(I);
```

That looks like a particularly bad use of goto, jumping out of the for loop like that.  I assume it works (since you're using it), but it would give me the willies.

Comment: Woah. That works, I'm not 100% sure why but I just tested it and it does. Very nice.

Comment: Alright, I see why it works now. Because you are counting down it doesn't matter that the list shrinks. The subsequent indexes will all be valid. I'm going to go change my stupid code now.

Comment: Keep in mind Larry's solution is a well known standard solution to this particular problem (index-based deletion), applicable in a whole lot more situations than just "Delphi" and/or "TObjectList". It's an important tool to have in your belt.

Comment: And basically, it shows that the use of Goto is still not needed for this problem. :-) In my 20+ years of Pascal programming experience I've learned that if you consider the use of goto, you're missing a much better solution. I've never, ever needed to use this silly command.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use

```
  I := 0;
  while I < ObjectList.Count do begin
    if TMyClass(ObjectList[I]).ShouldRemove then ObjectList.Delete(I)
    else Inc(I);
  end;
```

Comment: That's a nice solution as well! Thanks.

Comment: Yep! Good one. But how about doing a reverse loop? `For I := Prec(ObjectList.count) downto 0 do if TMyClass(ObjectList[I]).ShouldRemove then ObjectList.Delete(I)` ? Which has been suggested already. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The only *valid* use of Goto I've seen is the one supplied in Delphi's help.

```
for I := 0 to something do
begin
  for J := 0 to something do
  begin
    For K := 0 to something do
    begin
      if SomeCondition then
        Goto NestedBreak
    end;
  end;
end;
NestedBreak:
```

Though Goto could be avoided in that exemple by moving the loop in a local function and using EXIT, for exemple.  If a subfunction is not acceptable, you can still do that:

```
for I := 0 to something do
begin
  for J := 0 to something do
  begin
    For K := 0 to something do
    begin
      if SomeCondition then
      begin
        GottaBreak := True
        Break;
      end; 
    end;
    if GottaBreak then Break;
  end;
  if GottaBreak then Break;
end;
```

This is just sligthly less optimal.

I have yet to see a single other situation where a Goto would be the best solution.(Or any good at all).

Goto in itself is NOT bad.  It's a flow control command just like EXIT, BREAK or CONTINUE.  Except that those other are restricted to specific situations and are managed by the compiler correctly. (With that being said, some programmer I spoke with consider those as being as harmful as Goto, a view I don't share)  Goto being unrestricted, the things you can do with it can have very negative impacts. Anyway, I think I went a bit beyond the scope of the question already. ^_^

Comment: Ken, you could just wrap a try...except around the loops and use Abort; instead of the goto. I think I would prefer that.

Comment: Exceptions have a much... MUCH bigger performance hit than the "if GottaBreak then" solution. Try...Except is bad for performance.  It shouldn't be used for "normal" flow.

Comment: Today's processors are fast enough that you don't have to worry about the performance impact of raising a single exception to escape from a loop.

Comment: Today's processor have so much performance, lets waste some!  Seriously, here's some reading for you. http://www.stevetrefethen.com/blog/BDS2006slowcompiletimesandthecostofexceptions.aspx

Comment: @David, using Abort in that way is just a Goto in disguise and also disguise the true purpose. As for the performance impact: let's not waste some if there are better and much clearer solutions to be found. Using an exception for (local) flow control is not the clearest way of coding and considered bad practice by many.

Comment: Ken: jumping out a bunch (even 2) of nested IFs is also faster. (at least in D2006). Similar case though. I have one or two in my innerloop of my image processing (blob finding) routines.  FPC recently implemented interprocedural goto btw (ISO feature).

Comment: It's a good example, although you could replace the for-loop with a while-loop and check for two conditions. I really hate the use of the break command too. It just makes developers lazy, since there are nicer alternatives to jump out of a loop. (Besides, a while-loop provides more control over the loop, plus it maintains the value of the loop variable when you end the loop.)

Comment: @Ken, thank you, that was a very interesting read. I didn't realize exceptions could cause that much of a performance hit. I will avoid using them in normal program flow from now on.

Comment: @Marjan, after reading Ken's link I now agree with you. I'll avoid using exceptions like this in the future. PS. Any relation to Wietse Venema?